# boost::multiprecision::uint128_t sizeof is 16

Tags: boost, boost-multiprecision

Per this link,

[boost::multiprecision::uint128_t sizeof is 24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876253/boostmultiprecisionuint128-t-sizeof-is-24)

uint128_t should be 24.

I tried it on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 x64, and it says 16.

Any reason?

Answer (score 2):

cpp_int_base uses some auxiliary variables

```cpp
   data_type   m_data;

   unsigned    m_limbs;
   bool        m_sign, m_internal;
```